# Evento ajax não executa com modal

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho esse ajax. Chamo uma modal, que em tese, quando clicasse em um id, executaria esse ajax, porém não executa.

```
 $("#ClassificacaoId").on('change click', function () {
            valor = $('#ClassificacaoId').val();
            if (valor === "1") {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'GetContratoPedido',
                    data: { dado: valor },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (dados) {
                        if (dados !== null) {

                            var selectbox = $('#contrato');
                            $.each(dados, function (i, d) {
                                $('<option>').val(d.id).text(d.value).appendTo(selectbox);
                            });


                            $("#cmbPedido").fadeIn(500);
                        }

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log("Falha de enviar AJAX");
                    }
                })
            }
            else if (valor === "2") {

                $("#cmbPedido").fadeOut();
            } else if (valor === "3") {
                $("#cmbPedido").fadeOut();
            }
        });

        $("#contrato").on('click', function () {
            contrato = $("#contrato").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'GetContratos',
                data: { dado: contrato },
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (dados) {
                    if (dados !== 0) {

                        var selectbox = $('#itensContrato');
                        $.each(dados, function (i, d) {
                            $('<option>').val(d.id).text(d.value).appendTo(selectbox);
                        });


                        $("#cmbItensContrato").fadeIn(500);
                    } else {
                        $("#cmbItensContrato").fadeOut(500);
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("Erro ao enviar AJAX");
                }
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Se quando da declaração de eventos através da função jQuery .on(), ainda não existirem os elementos no html, esses eventos não serão accionados. Nesse caso deverá deferir a sua execução, por exemplo:
Se quando da declaração de eventos através da função jQuery .on(), ainda não existirem os elementos no html, esses eventos não serão accionados. Nesse caso deverá deferir a sua execução, por exemplo:

```
$('body').on('click', '#future-element-id', function () {
    ...
});
```

'#future-element-id' será um elemento html que apenas irá existir mais tarde.

Se o elemento não existe, quando da declaração do evento, o evento não será acionado desta forma:

```
$('#future-element-id').on('click', function () {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Isso que estava procurando e não lembrava haha

Comment: Ainda bem que pude ajudar